# How to get the rendering time time in chrome

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome, browser, render

I want to calculate how much time spend for rendering when I change styles of nodes.
For examples : There is a <ul> node, and has 100000 <li> nodes inside. With jQuery, I want to change color of all <li> nodes to red. so, I have code like this:

`var time = new Date;`

`$( 'ul li' ).css( 'color', 'red' );`

`console.log( new Date - time );`

After I load the page, I got a time for executing "$( 'ul li' ).css( 'color', 'red' );". But after that, The list showing on page is still not red, it changed 2 or 3 seconds later.

So I want to know that how to get the real time for whole rendering by browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
console.time("Test");
console.timeEnd("Test");
```

[API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.time)

Comment: Thank you very much. But it is still not working as I want. the console.timeEnd will print the time in a short time, and the real style, we can see in browser, changes several seconds later.